# Is there any alternative way to write this t-sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these 3 tables:

[image: DB Diagram]

For each car I need to visualize the data about the last (most recent) reservation:

- the car model (Model);
- the user who reserved the car (Username);
- when it was reserved (ReservedOn);
- when it was returned (ReservedUntil).

If there is no reservation for a given car, I have to show only the car model. Other fields must be empty.

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT 
  Reservations.CarId, 
  res.MostRecent, 
  Reservations.UserId, 
  Reservations.ReservedOn, 
  Reservations.ReservedUntil 
FROM 
  Reservations 
  JOIN (
    Select 
      Reservations.CarId, 
      MAX(Reservations.ReservedOn) AS 'MostRecent' 
    FROM 
      Reservations 
    GROUP BY 
      Reservations.CarId
  ) AS res ON res.carId = Reservations.CarId 
  AND res.MostRecent = Reservations.ReservedOn
```

[image: Expected something like this]

This first one works but I got stuck to obtain the result that I need. How could I write complete the query?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih Hi, I edited my post to show the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a classic top-n-per-group problem.

One way to do it is to use `OUTER APPLY`. It is a correlated subquery (lateral join), which returns the latest Reservation for each row in the `Cars` table. If such reservation doesn't exist for a certain car, there will be nulls.

If you create an index for `Reservations` table on `(CarID, ReservedOn DESC)`, this query should be more efficient than self-join.

```
SELECT
    Cars.CarID
    ,Cars.Model
    ,A.ReservedOn
    ,A.ReservedUntil
    ,A.UserName
FROM
    Cars
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1)
            Reservations.ReservedOn
            ,Reservations.ReservedUntil
            ,Users.UserName
        FROM
            Reservations
            INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UserId = Reservations.UserId
        WHERE
            Reservations.CarID = Cars.CarID
        ORDER BY
            Reservations.ReservedOn DESC
    ) AS A
;
```

---

For other approaches to this common problem see [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841605/4116017)

and [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86415/57105)

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thank you for your answer. I can't use an OUTER APPLY. It is something like an exercise and I have some limitations. As you can read in my post, my first idea was to group reservations by the car ID and find the most recent one. Then, I join to it the reservations table. Now I have all the informations I need except... I have to add car models that have not a reservation entry in the reservations table. It is here that I got stuck. Any suggestions?

Comment: @dodido, Well, simply left join `Cars` with your whole query. Your query returns one row per `CarID` that exists in the `Reservations`. Fine. `SELECT ... FROM Cars LEFT JOIN (Your query) AS T ON Cars.CarID = T.CarID`. It is not efficient, but it will work.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, you mean:

[example](https://i.ibb.co/s5gGPwk/query.jpg)?

I get: the column 'CarId' was specified multiple times for 't'.

Comment: Ok, this one should work: [solution] (https://i.ibb.co/ssD8nv9/query-solution.jpg).

Comment: @dodido, it is great that you managed to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With `not exists`:

```
select r.* from reservations r
where not exists (
  select 1 from reservations  
  where carid = r.carid and reservedon > r.reservedon
)
```

You can create a `CTE` with the above code and join it to the other tables:

```
with cte as (
    select r.* from reservations r
    where not exists (
      select 1 from reservations  
      where carid = r.carid and reservedon > r.reservedon
    )
)
select c.carid, c.model, u.username, cte.reservedon, cte.reserveduntil
from cars c
left join cte on c.carid = cte.carid 
left join users u on u.userid = cte.userid
```

If you don't want to use a CTE:

```
select c.carid, c.model, u.username, t.reservedon, t.reserveduntil
from cars c
left join (
    select r.* from reservations r
    where not exists (
      select 1 from reservations  
      where carid = r.carid and reservedon > r.reservedon
    )
) t on c.carid = t.carid 
left join users u on u.userid = t.userid
```

Comment: Hi @forpas, thank you for your answer. Is there any way to complete my query without creating a CTE?

Comment: So the reservedon column and the reserveduntil one are related to the most recent reservation. Looks like I get 2 more results than expected, I'll check again. Thank you! So the query that I wrote was not correct?

Comment: The code checks only for reservedon to be the latest.

Comment: Is there a case that in the table reservations the same carid can have more thsn 1 rows with the same reservedon date?

Comment: Yes. If you have two identical cars, they can be reserved the same day from different users. So, my idea to solve it (the subquery I wrote) isn't correct? EDIT: imagine a 'numbersOfCars' column in the cars table.

Comment: When you say *two identical cars*  do you mean that they have the same carid?

Comment: I edited the code to include the carid in the results.

Comment: Yes, I mean they have the same ID but different 'numbersOf' value. Ok, so my 'group by' was wrong I guess. Is there any suggestion / link that can help me to approach this kind of queries?

Comment: Where is this numbersOf value? If it is unique for each car It should be the primary key in the table cars and you should store this in the table reservations instead of carid.

Comment: It is not unique. It is in the 'cars' table just to specify how many cars (same model) are there.

Comment: No. Two car models can have the same numbersof but have different ID.

Comment: Sorry, it comes from a series of exercises and probably I wasn't clear enough in my description. Nevertheless, your answer is helping me.